# Matlab vs C calculation

Tags: c, matlab

I am trying to convert Matlab code into c code, I verifying each step with Matlab result. everything matches except for subtraction the error scale is 1e-14 but due iterations it affects the whole answer.

Matlab:

```
 s = c-A'*y;
```

c code:

```
 for (i=0;i<A_cols;i++)
{
 s[i][0] = c[i][0]-Temp_Mat_0[i][0];
}
```

I have done this (A'*y) aside and matched it to Matlab code

I entered the same values for both, but the are saved or displayed as follows:
Values are:

```
  A_example[16]= {8,1,1,2,-1,5,23,7,5,8,10,1,12,-1,5,23};
  b_example[16]= {5.3326,12.8165,10.0277,19.4862};
  c_example[16]= {13.3215,4.0611,24.2008,27.7622};
```

c code: saves as as

[image]

output for s:

[image]

Matlab Output is:

```
K>> full(A)

ans =

     8     1     1     2
    -1     5    23     7
     5     8    10     1
    12    -1     5    23

K>> full(b)

ans =

    5.3326
   12.8165
   10.0277
   19.4862

K>> full(c)

ans =

   13.3215
    4.0611
   24.2008
   27.7622

s =

   1.0e-13 *

   -0.0355
    0.1599
   -0.1421
    0.0711
```

this error in addition to other errors based on subtraction makes my c code calculations drifting very far! is there any way to make both codes work with the same precision?

Comment: I am using double for everything

Comment: Please take a look at the discussion of floating point arithmetic in the linked duplicate. Your errors appear to be at the limit of machine precision for double precision variables, and the differences likely arise from differences in the order of operations between the two solutions.